# "by" and "in" with "way"

Tags: prepositions

I got interested in the difference between "by" and "in" when we're talking about "way".
I found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155099/312479) that "by" means the same as "in" but "by" is more formal:

> *Recursion is the way **in/by** which a function is specified in terms of itself*.

---

So I decided to take a couple examples from a [dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/way):
**(1a)** *She explains things **in** a way that children can understand*.
**(2a)** *He spoke **in** a calm and gentle way*.

Do they remain correct with "*by*" instead of "*in*":
**(1b)** *She explains things **by** a way that children can understand*.
**(2b)** *He spoke **by** a calm and gentle way*.

---

Also I found another example [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/es/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/participle-clauses):

> "Furiously" is an adverb of manner. It just shows the way in which one action is done, not the way by which one action is done.

Is this sentence logically correct in terms of using "in" and "by"?
Can't I say "*the action was done **by** fury*"?

Comment: None of your examples are correct with "by". I can't explain why tho

Answer (score 0):

Assalomu alaykum

You are using the prep **in** in order to make adverb, with a help of a structure: **in + adj + way/manner or in a way/manner that is...**.

> She is dancing in a beautiful way/manner.
> (It is {the structure} only describing a verb which adverb always does.)

In this case you can't use **by** because it cannot give the meaning that **in** gives, that's why your *1b* and *2b* sentences are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

“In a way that …” is idiomatic. “By a way that …” is not.

The answer that you cite does not really address the question asked. Notice that the answer has not been upvoted once in almost nine years. Furthermore, the question itself involved communicating about mathematics, a field with a specialized jargon of its own.

Let’s try from scratch.

> She explained it by a simple method

> She explained it in a simple way

Both mean the same thing, and either may used in formal writing, but the second probably would be far more common in speech or an email.

Prepositions are frequently constrained by usage rather than some distinction in the formal meaning of the prepositions themselves.

Usage favors “in a manner” or “in a way” rather than “by a manner” or “by a way.”

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+way+that%2C+by+a+way+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20way%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20a%20way%20that%3B%2Cc0

Similarly, usage favors “by a method” rather than “in a method.”

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+method+that%2C+by+a+method+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20method%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20a%20method%20that%3B%2Cc0

Which preposition goes with which verbs or nouns is not always subject to logical rules. Sometimes, you just have to learn from experience, which is of course how native speakers learn to use prepositions. The peculiarities of English prepositions must be exasperating to learners. I certainly found the subtleties between “en” and “dans” in French exasperating.

I do venture a general guideline, however. Prepositional phrases that describe the manner or emotion of an actor often use “in”

> She spoke in gentle tones

> She raged in grief

Prepositional phrases that describe the means an actor used often use “by.”

> She taught by the Socratic method

> He reached his conclusions by uncannily prescient intuition rather than by carefully designed experiment.

Unfortunately, this is not some adamantine rule.

> He taught in parables

or

> He taught by parables

are equally idiomatic. They may imply virtually subliminal differences in meaning, but 99.9% of native speakers would have difficulty in identifying, let alone justifying, any difference in meaning.